# OSX Architecture related

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am developing an application for Mac 10.7 and above (10.7, 10.8, and 10.9 for now).
Based on my search on web -

1. OSX 10.8 and 10.9 only comes with 64bit flavour
2. OSX 10.7 supports both 32bit and 64bit Intel.
3. IN OSX 10.7 - If I develop for 64bit(x86_64) then application will work in 32bit as well.
   https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3200553.
   In this case, How ARC handled internally?

Can someone please validate and confirm my assumptions above?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86_64 is **not** emulated on 32 bit machines, so if you want your code to work on those, you'll have to build for it. The discussion you're linking to discusses *kernel* architecture, which is irrelevant for your purposes.

ARC does not work in 32 bit code, so if you want to support 32 bit machines, you cannot build with ARC (and yes, like many such tradeoffs, choosing to support the older alternative adds work and is potentially error prone).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to check the release notes. But if you try to compile for 32bit with a target SDK that doesn't support it Xcode will loudly tell you.

The last sold 32bit Macs were years ago. I'm but sure the hardware is even supported now. 
You will benefit greatly from targeting 64bit only and the latest release possible. With the new strategy to make updates free, it keeps things simple.

Comment: Targeting 10.7 or even 10.6 is still a good idea depending on the app -type and user-base. I for example have a very specialized app dealing with bat calls and not the typical Mac users. Many still have 10.6 running, some even 10.5 ... and my main development machine also still runs 10.7. I am always annoyed if support is dropped too quickly. So I wouldn't recommend to just always go for the latest released version... but I fully agree with dropping 32bit support

Comment: Thanks. I need to support from 10.7 and above.I may decide to stop 32bit, however there may be some 10.7 user who has 32bit intel.My question is will my 64bit app works on 32bit intel?

Comment: Sure. I'm speaking of the broader market and what is really feasible within a timeframe and a limit of resources. If you've already got something, there's no rush to exclude older versions. But often with new development from scratch, it leaves you a much simpler path.

Comment: @RamaprasadUpadhyaya: a 64-bit-only app will never run on a 32-bit-only CPU (i.e. a [a Core Solo or Core Duo CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Macintosh_models_grouped_by_CPU_type#P6), no matter what the OS version is.